# Parse Text file in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to read input from a text file(read only numbers in arraylist). My text file looks like this containing numbers(146,7,-1,-2,3).It looks like this actually:
HEADER
1467-1-23

Now,when I put HEADER string in the file,my code would not read the first number which is 146 in my case and starts with the second number "7".However,when the string HEADER is not there,146 is also read which is obviously what I want.My code is this:

```
String pathToWrite="C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Hello.txt";

 FileReader fr=new FileReader(pathToWrite);
     BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(fr);

     String aLine=null;
     int numberOfLine=0;
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();


    while((aLine=bufferedReader.readLine()) != null )
     {
            if(numberOfLine > 1) //since header lies in first line,I want to skip that line
            {
             list.add(Integer.parseInt(aLine));
            }
             numberOfLine++;


     }
```

Want suggestions about how I can change the code to read the first number too?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean the first line which is skipped ?

Comment: No,I mean how to read the first number in the list which is 146 in my case.The first line would be skipped as I am putting the if statement

Comment: From `1467-1-23` number - How do you make out that `146` is one number and 7 is another. Is the format fixed? For ex, I can say `146` is actually 3 numbers - `1`, `4` and `6`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your if statment or numberOfLine=0; variable. You can do one of the following

Case 1:

```
int numberOfLine=0;

while((aLine=bufferedReader.readLine()) != null )
     {
            if(numberOfLine >= 1) //since header lies in first line,I want to skip that line
            {
             list.add(Integer.parseInt(aLine));
            }
             numberOfLine++;


     }
```

============================================================
Case 2:

```
int numberOfLine=1;

while((aLine=bufferedReader.readLine()) != null )
     {
            if(numberOfLine > 1) //since header lies in first line,I want to skip that line
            {
             list.add(Integer.parseInt(aLine));
            }
             numberOfLine++;


     }
```

Answer (score 1):

The file looks like:

```
HEADER
146
7
1
23
```

? Then try `if(numberOfLine > 0)`. It's because you are beginning counting from zero.

Answer (score 0):

Split your line using String's split function

```
String [] numbers = aLine.split(",");
```

This will give you all numbers in an array.

I hope it resolves your query !!!

Answer (score 0):

Typical `>` vs. `>=` typo. Just change `if(numberOfLine > 1)` to `if(numberOfLine >= 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

The file looks like this?

```
HEADER 1467-1-23
```

if like this, give an example of second line. Because this is one line which id = 0;
or like this?

```
HEADER
1467-1-23
...
```